# Installing library for Coq via Opam on Windows

Tags: ocaml, coq, opam

I'm know nothing in programming. During the installation via Opam library Math Classes in Coq i received an ERROR. I don't know what to do, no idea. The same ERROR occurs when i try to install Bignums or C-CoRN.

Could you give me a hint,advice or any plan to handle this please.

The way build and install manually on my computer doesn't work either.

Maybe this ERROR because i've used OCaml installer for Windows?

The compilation of coq failed at

```
    "/home/203/.opam/4.10.0/.opam-switch/build/coq.8.11.1/./configure
    -configdir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/lib/coq/config -prefix
    /home/203/.opam/4.10.0 -mandir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/man -docdir
    /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/doc -libdir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/lib/coq
    -datadir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/share/coq -coqide no".
```

ERROR while compiling coq.8.11.1

context     2.0.4 | cygwin/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.10.0 | https://opam.ocaml.org#88a179f5
path        ~/.opam/4.10.0/.opam-switch/build/coq.8.11.1
command  ~/.opam/4.10.0/.opam-switch/build/coq.8.11.1/./configure -configdir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/lib/coq/config -prefix 
/home/203/.opam/4.10.0 -mandir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/man -docdir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/doc -libdir 
/home/203/.opam/4.10.0/lib/coq -datadir /home/203/.opam/4.10.0/share/coq -coqide no

exit-code   2

env-file    ~/.opam/log/coq-1451-e4db2f.env

output-file ~/.opam/log/coq-1451-e4db2f.out

output

0 [main] ocamlrun 1488 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dllunix.so' (0x200000) is already occupied

0 [main] ocamlrun 1489 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dllunix.so' (0x200000) is already occupied

0 [main] ocamlrun 1490 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dllunix.so' (0x200000) is already occupied

0 [main] ocamlrun 1491 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dllunix.so' (0x200000) is already occupied

0 [main] ocamlrun 1492 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'dllunix.so' (0x200000) is already occupied

I can not automatically find the name of your architecture.

Give me a name, please [win32 for Win95, Win98 or WinNT]:
 Exception: End_of_file.

Comment: Coq (or Ocaml) is made by teams who are much more enthusiast about Linux than about Winndows. My strong recommandation is to install some [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer, such as [ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) or [debian](http://debian.org/) - and both are packaging `coq`

Comment: Looking at the page https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Installation-of-Coq-on-Windows it looks like working with `opam` on windows is broken until a fix is made to cygwin.

Comment: Could you please explain, for Educational purposes of course, what does this error mean?

Comment: It's unlikely there's an educational interpretation of that error beyond "Opam doesn't with Cygwin".